# Can we determine structure the automorphism group of all infinite abelian groups?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be a infinite abelian group .
We know that we can determine structure the automorphisms group of  all finite  abelian groups.

Can we determine structuer the automorphisms group of  all infinite  abelian groups?

Thank you

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: Perhaps we should first ask for a classification of all abelian groups, before we want to completely determine all their automorphism groups.

Comment: Infinite abelian groups can be beasts covered by a lamb skin...beware of them!

Comment: You say "We know that we can determine (the) structure (of) the automorphism group of all finite abelian groups". However, according to [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0605185) paper, the automorphism groups of finite abelian groups seem to have passed the literature by. (The paper does give a complete characterisation of them though.)

Answer (score 1):

We don't even know what all the infinite abelian groups are, much less do we have a description of their automorphism groups.  [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/313737/status-of-the-classification-of-non-finitely-generated-abelian-groups) question has some information about that.

Finitely generated abelian groups we have a better knowledge of, in particular of tame automorphisms, but these are not completely classified either.  In fact, even the automorphism groups of finite abelian groups are hard to describe in general.

Comment: By *tame* automorphisms, do you mean those automorphisms which lift to automorphisms of the ambient free group?