# Decomposition of Infinitely Generated Abelian Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am curious if there is any structure result for an infinitely generated abelian group $G$?

In particular, is the following naive guess true?

$$G\cong \bigoplus_{i\in A}\mathbb{Z}\oplus \bigoplus_{i\in B
}\mathbb{Z}_{q_i}$$

where $A$, $B$ are some infinite sets, and $\mathbb{Z}_{qi}$ are primary cyclic groups.

Or perhaps it is not a direct sum, i.e.

$$G\cong \prod_{i\in A}\mathbb{Z}\times \prod_{i\in B
}\mathbb{Z}_{q_i}$$?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think it's not true if you use the implied addition on the right hand side of your equation. I don't think you can write a group isomorphism between the additive group $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ and a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: This has been asked multiple times. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/313737/status-of-the-classification-of-non-finitely-generated-abelian-groups), and [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22646/structure-theorem-for-abelian-torsion-groups-that-are-not-finitely-generated)

Comment: @desiigner You are correct: every quotient of $\mathbb{Q}$ is finite, so we would need $\mathbb{Q}\cong X\times Y$ for some finite group $X$. However, every element of $\mathbb{Q}$ has infinite order so we cannot embed any finite group $X$ into $\mathbb{Q}$, a contradiction.